# How to refer to a local variable name through another string variable in MYSQL user defined function?

Tags: mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function in MYSQL in which i need to refer to local variable name dynamically (indirectly). i.e.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE D1 INT;
DECLARE i INT;
SET i = 1;
SET D1 = 7;
RETURN variable("D" & i);
END
```

*Note: I used supposed function variable() in above example to show what I want.*

I want the function to return value of **D1** but referring to its name indirectly using another variable **i**. How can I do that? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in MySQL. Why do you need to do this? Are you trying to simulate an array? Use a temporary table instead.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to do this with `PREPARE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE D1 INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE result INT;
    SET i = 1;
    SET D1 = 7;
    PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT D', i, ' INTO result');
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    RETURN result;
END
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I was trying to simulate an array. I have also found a way around using JSON Array. But your solution is just what I wanted.